# Add class to <html> on link click and add delay Redirection (fade out page)

Tags: javascript, jquery, transition, fade, css-transitions

I'm trying to add page transitions. The fadeIn transition is done using the WebFont Loader and CSS animations. What I want is to add a class to the `html` tag on link click and wait 1 second (for the CSS fadeOut animation), then redirect to the link.

This is an altered version of [this jQuery code](http://www.onextrapixel.com/2010/02/23/how-to-use-jquery-to-make-slick-page-transitions/):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("a").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    redirectLink = this.href;
    $("body").fadeOut(1000, redirectToLink);      
  });

  function redirectToLink() {
    window.location = redirectLink;
  }
});
```

I have customized it, but I believe there's a problem with `.delay(1000, redirectToLink)` and it's not working. I don't have much knowledge of JS, so I would really appreciate your help.

```
$(document).ready(function() {


  $("a").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    redirectLink = this.href;
    $("html").addClass('wf-next').removeClass('wf-active wf-inactive wf-loading').delay(1000, redirectToLink);      
  });

  function redirectToLink() {
    window.location = redirectLink;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

.delay() is meant to be used with animations, but you've moved the animation to a css transition. I would use setTimeout instead like this:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $("a").click(function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      redirectLink = this.href;
      $("html").addClass('wf-next').removeClass('wf-active wf-inactive wf-loading');
      setTimeout(function(){
        redirectToLink(redirectLink);
      }, 1000);
    });

    function redirectToLink(url) {
      window.location = url;
    }
  });
```

Comment: Yes delay is just putting up a delay using settimeout is better in such situations

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {


    $("a").click(function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      redirectLink = this.href;
      $("html").addClass('wf-next').removeClass('wf-active wf-inactive wf-loading').fadeIn(1000, function(){ redirectToLink(redirectLink) } );      
    });

    function redirectToLink(url) {
      window.location = url;
    }
  });
```

Comment: Doesn't work either, the link is redirected immediately on click.
Take a look: http://reitermark.us/lab/loading/index.html
(click the reload link at the bottom)

Comment: This would probably work, but it doesn't make much sense to use a JS fadeIn to get a CSS fadeOut to work.